# How to pass the argument to a methods requiring Class<? extends something>?

Tags: java, generics

I've seen code like this:

`void foo(Class<? extends SomeInterface> clazz)`

I have a class like:

`class ClassA implements SomeInterface`

When I was trying:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
foo(a);
```

Eclipse gave something like "method not applicable".

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `foo` method takes a `Class` object as a parameter, not an instance of that class.

Try using the class literal instead:

```
foo(ClassA.class);
```

`ClassA.class` is the class literal for the `ClassA` class, and it's a `Class<ClassA>`, which fits the parameter description `Class<? extends SomeInterface>`.

For `foo(a);` to compile, the signature of `foo` would have been different:

```
void foo(SomeInterface bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Class` itself is an object, and `foo(` needs a bounded wildcard of a `Class` object.

If `ClassA` indeed implements/extends `SomeInterface`(one or the other, you used different terms), then pass `ClassA.class`. The `class` keyword specifies to get a class *object*.